# Having Difficulty Reading Data From a File in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble with this project for school and could use some help getting started. I'm given a file that contains movie titles, the year they were made, and their genres then I'm supposed to create a linked list with the information. Each line in the file looks something like this:

`1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy`

If the user decides to search by the movie title and enters `Toy Story`, it should display both the name and year of the movie: `Toy Story (1995)` If the user decides to search by genre it should display every movie that contains the genre. Lastly, if the user wants to remove a movie, they enter the movie title and it should be deleted from the linked list along with its other information.

So the problem I'm having so far is reading in the data. When I read in the data I am able to remove the `::` and `|` and store everything in a vector but now each element of the vector is one word, meaning that if I were to print out `vect[1]` for example it would be `Toy` (since `vect[0]` would be `1` as I don't know how to remove the leading numbers which is another problem).

So how would I go about keeping the title of the movie together so I can add it to a linked list and vice versa for the genres and years?  Also, will I need to create three linked lists, one being the movie titles, one being the years and the other being the genres?

I don't have much code, since my problem is right at the beginning but this is what I have so far. It goes through the file and removes the `::` and `|` and stores it into a vector. I don't know how I should precede from here or even if this would be the correct way to start for this type of problem.

```
   while(inFile >> value)
   {
       istringstream iss(value);
       string line;

       while(getline(iss, line))
       {
           size_t prev = 0, pos;
           while ((pos = line.find_first_of("|:", prev)) != string::npos)
           {
               if (pos > prev)
               {
                   vect.push_back(line.substr(prev, pos-prev));
               }
               prev = pos + 1;
           }
           if (prev < line.length())
           {
                vect.push_back(line.substr(prev, string::npos));
           }
       }
    }
```

I'm not one to usually ask for help but I'm completely stuck and have no idea how to continue. Any help would be appreciated! If I need to clarify anything let me know.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, in a debugger, to figure out where it's start doing what you didn't expect?

Comment: Question cannot be answered without psychic powers or guesswork. For example, what is `value`? You code seems predicated on it containing quite a bit of data because it's going to be sliced up with a `stringstream`, but `>>` generally stops after reading one whitespace-delimited token.

Comment: @user4581301 value is a string that'll hold each line to be "sliced" up until it's overridden by the next line.

Comment: `>>` into a `std::string` grabs one and only one word. You won't get a line with `inFile >> value`. Use `std::getline` for that. Best I can do for you without a lot more information.

Comment: @user4581301 when I `cout << value` I get the full line, just with no spaces. Then I "slice" it up and push it to a vector. Each element of the vector is one word in the line. Here's a screenshot of the output of the vector, so `vector[1]` is `toy` and `vector[2]` is `story` and so on : https://gyazo.com/c9839df7c7a4b11bdc39f5bb5b4c5e15

Comment: Afraid not. Given "1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy", `inFile >> value` will stop at "1::Toy". The next loop will set `value` to "Story" and the third iteration will get "(1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy"

Comment: Example: http://ideone.com/3SEIMB This is what the MCVE @Dan requested is all about: reducing the code until the problem is obvious.

Comment: @user4581301 I see, so what would you suggest I do to get the whole line? I'm now trying to get the index of the first and last `::` and use `substr` to get the information between it but because of the problem you brought to my attention, I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Chuck the `while(inFile >> value)` loop and the `stringstream`. Change `while(getline(iss, line))` to `while(getline(inFile , line))`.  [Now you have a line.](http://ideone.com/5YGg9d)

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat it as a string. Write a data-structure to contain the information.

```
struct movie {
   std::string title;
   std::string year;
   std::vector<std::string> genres;
};
```

Then, as you parse each line, fill in an instance of this structure. Once you finish parsing the line, push the structure to your list. This will enable you to do searching later on. You can also add stream operators to the struct for printing it to the screen in a clean format.

Comment: I think what has got me stuck is reading the data. How would I go about determining what is the title, year, and genre if I removed the `::` and `|` delimiters? Since now they're all just separated by spaces.

Comment: @RyanBeatty You write a Finite State Machine. Memorize the FSM pattern. It is the answer to every string parsing question you will ever be asked.

Comment: @RyanBeatty But the sloppy way to do it is to use get the index of "::" starting at 0, then get the index of ( starting at 0.  Then use substring based on those indexes. And so on....

Comment: So would I then remove only the `|` delimiter?

Comment: @RyanBeatty This is getting dangerously close to "write my code/do my homework for me", and since this is for school and I (in a generic sense) will one day be working with you, using software you write, or having my life depend on technology you invent, I'm going to say, you can handle this. You've got the algorithm, you know what you need to do--the rest is up to you.

Comment: Wasn't my intention to have you write it for me just wanted confirmation. You actually really helped me a lot, I think I can figure it out now. Thanks!